# How to create a html link to a specific product category

Tags: hyperlink, categories

I am using GoDaddy's website builder after years of working in Wordpress. I have created pages with modulesthat link to categories but the button and image is opening the shop category in a new tab.

The only way I can have it open in the same window is to broadly link to the shop and have people drill down to the correct subcategory.

GoDaddy does not have a "link to category" option like woocommerce does. Only a "link to page" or "link to website url" (which works but opens the link in a new tab). So I am going to try doing it in an html block.

I'm not a coder but can manage. I have images that I can use as "buttons" and am thinking I need the code that creates the link and incorporates the catagory link which I can grab from the shop view but also tells it to open to "self" (same window).

Am I making sense?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: hello, without code we can't tell what you want to do [see how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Sandeep Sharma
I actually decided to go back to my Wordpress build of the site which already has the link to category functionality. The HTML block in the website builder did not allow more than a snippet of code so I could tell the html workaround for linking to internal categories was not worth exploring. Hopefully, GoDaddy will add that functionality to the platform. I'm not considering it a waste of time because the their builder template led me in a different direction in terms of graphics, colors, and navigation and I'm much happier with it.